# Spivak, Ch. 22, "Infinite Sequences" Prob 16: Prove that if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=l$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_1+...+a_n}{n}=l$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

The following is a problem in Chapter 22 "Infinite Sequences" from Spivak's *Calculus*.

> 16. Prove that if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=l$ then
>
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_1+...+a_n}{n}=l$$

I found the $\epsilon-\delta$ proof to be quite tricky. Writing it out here as a question has helped me already, and at this point I am a tad more confident that maybe the solution below is correct.

**Here is my solution**

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=l$ means that

$$\forall\epsilon>0\ \exists >0\ \forall n, n\in\mathbb{N}\land (n>N)\implies |a_n-l|<\epsilon\tag{1}$$

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $\epsilon_1=\epsilon/2$.

Let $N$ such that $n>N\implies |a_n-l|<\epsilon_1$.

Let $n>N$. Then

$$\frac{[n-(N+1)](l-\epsilon_1)}{n}<\frac{a_{N+1}+...+a_n}{n}<\frac{[n-(N+1)](l+\epsilon_1)}{n}<\frac{n(l+\epsilon_1)}{n}=l+\epsilon_1\tag{2}$$

Consider the leftmost expression. We have

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{[n-(N+1)](l-\epsilon_1)}{n}=l-\epsilon_1\tag{3}$$

Hence, there is some $M$ such that $$n>M\implies l-\epsilon_1-\epsilon_1<\frac{[n-(N+1)](l-\epsilon_1)}{n}<l-\epsilon_1+\epsilon_1\tag{4}$$

$$l-\epsilon<\frac{[n-(N+1)](l-\epsilon_1)}{n}<l\tag{5}$$

Then

$$n>M\implies l-\epsilon<\frac{a_{N+1}+...+a_n}{n}<l+\epsilon\tag{6}$$

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{N+1}+...+a_n}{n}=l\tag{7}$$

Finally

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_1+...+a_n}{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_1+...+a_N}{n}+\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{N+1}+...+a_{n}}{n}\tag{8}$$

$$=0+l$$

$$=l$$

**Is this solution correct?**

Comment: The number of terms in the sum $a_{N+1}+\dots+a_n$ is not $n-(N+1)$ but $n-N.$

Comment: $[n-N](l+\epsilon_1)<n(l+\epsilon_1)$ is false if $l+\epsilon_1<0.$

Comment: Your proof is generally correct but you will have to make a distinction between positive and negative $l$ (and possibly $l=0$). Other than that, the overall logic looks good to me.

Comment: @AnneBauval I agree with both your points. However, both issues are minor, correct? The issue of $N$ versus $N+1$ is solved by letting $N$ such that $n\geq N\implies |a_n-l|<\epsilon$. As for the question of $l$ being negative, it seems that that means we have an analogous case to consider, but the proof of that case would be essentially the same.

Comment: Yes, you can easily correct both (I just answered your question). As for the second one, better don't separate the 2 cases (see the 2 proofs in the duplicate).